# What is this German document from the mid-1950s?

Tags: germany, 20th-century, birth-records, adoption

I've been asked to look into the ancestry of a friend of a friend, who was adopted mid-1950s in Germany.

She has a document, but doesn't know whether it's a birth certificate or something related to her adoption - can anyone identify it, and advise what the relevant (redacted) fields are?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a birth registration.

redacted are (in order):
[registration number unredacted]
[registration place unrededacted, Himmelsthür is now part of Hildesheim, Niedersachsen]
registration date [year unredacted]
mother's name [probably also her age, marital status and occupation, possibly birthplace and parents' names if reported]
mother's address
[husband's name and address left blank]
birth date [time unredacted]
? probably the birth place or address
boy or girl
gender-specific article
child's name
? probaby circumstances of the report
identification of the person reporting the birth
signature of that person
[registrar's signature unredacted]
parents' marriage date or mother's birthdate if illegitimate, registry blank
child's marriage blank, registry blank
death of the child blank, registry blank